# Is there a way to check if the Balkan Mountains passes are open?

Tags: online-resources, driving, bulgaria

The Balkan Mountains passes in Bulgaria are sometimes closed due to heavy snowfall and icy conditions. Is there a website where I can check which of them are open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Bulgaria automobile club has a [great website](http://www.uab.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=78&Itemid=111&lang=bg) showing which roads are open and which roads are closed. The only problem is that website in available only on Bulgarian, but it's possible to understand the information:

- The first section is about the highways (*Автомагистрали*)  -  their names begin with AM.
- The second section is about the passes (*Проходи*) - you can check the names on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balkan_Mountains#Passes). When the colour is red it means that the pass is closed (*затворен*), otherwise they are open (*отворен*) however it's possible that there are some restrictions, usually for trucks.